# PhoneGap/Cordova error when adding the platform android?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to add the platform `android` to the cordova project using command 
`cordova platform add android`
but it giving me following error stack-

```
  Creating android project...

   D:\Users\admin\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
  Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at D:\Users\admin\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:87:29
    at _rejected (D:\Users\admin\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:808:24)
    at D:\Users\admin\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (D:\Users\admin\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\Users\admin\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
    at D:\Users\admin\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:574:44
    at flush (D:\Users\admin\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
       Error: D:\Users\admin\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\create.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (D:\Users\admin\Application Data\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

I have googled it and found other answers and tried everything related to setting the path's

1) Installed ANT,Java,Android SDK
   2) Set path in environment variables for and, java and android sdk tools and platform tools 
   3) Restarted machine several times.

When i run java -version and ant -version i get

```
  D:\Users\admin>java -version
   java version "1.7.0_51"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode, sharing)

 D:\Users\admin>ant -version
   Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014
```

still I am getting this error.
Any help would be great.(I am on Windows XP - 32 bit)

Comment: Did you use the "Android SDK Manager" to install a SDK version?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating following environment variables :

ANT_HOME - E:\DevTools\apache-ant-1.9.4 (Set as per your installation folder)
JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51 (Set as per your installation folder)

make sure you have following paths added in your PATH System Variable :
(Set as per your installation folder of JAVA, ANT & Android SDK)

```
E:\DevTools\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;
E:\DevTools\Android\sdk\tools;
E:\DevTools\Android\sdk\platform-tools;
```

Restart the machine and see if that works...

Comment: Already did that didn't worked. I have already mentioned in question what have i tried. Thanks anyway.